# strcat_s adds strange characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have the following:

```
char confchar[MAX_PATH] = "\\dbstrings.cfg";
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
path_strip_filename(buffer);
```

Here I get the path of the actual working application. This is working so far. I'll get

```
c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\secdb\debug\
```

I use strcat_s to combine these:

```
char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2] ;
strcat_s(c_buffer, buffer);
strcat_s(c_buffer, confchar);
```

The string is made compatible to use for a lable:

```
System::String^ c_bufstr = gcnew String(c_buffer);
this->lbl_stat->Text = lbltxt;
```

now I get something like:

```
@1vc:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\secdb\debug\dbstrings.cfg
```

I also messed around with that MAX_PATH, replacing it with integers and so on. The result is the same. So what can I do to remove this @1v in front of the path?

Comment: 'char buffer[SomeSize] = {}' to get zero initialization

Answer (score 7):

```
char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2] ;
strcat_s(c_buffer, buffer); // <-- problem!
strcat_s(c_buffer, confchar);
```

`c_buffer` is uninitialized, so you need to either set its first element to 0 before calling `strcat_s`, or use `strcpy_s` instead of the first call to `strcat_s`.

Comment: ... `strcpy_s` making the most sense semantically, but being asymmetric with the sequence of operations of which it is a part.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all, it seems the problem is solved.

```
[...]
char buffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
[...]
char c_buffer[MAX_PATH*2] ;
strcpy_s(c_buffer, buffer);
strcat_s(c_buffer, confchar);
[...]
```

The string shown in the lable is now as it should be.